# Jupyter notebook Pandas Dataframe access not working

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I recently upgraded to Anaconda 3, amongst other upgrades/installs, and now I can't even do a simple dataframe access. Does anyone know what the issue is here? This is frustrating since this should be something so simple.

[image]

Comment: not that I am interested in your data, but can you at least print `df.columns.tolist()` output to your question please?

Comment: Yeah, i think this is either the age old space issue with your column name  as @coldspeed mentioned, please print and post the result of the above.

Comment: You probably have whitespaces or an invisible character around your column name (for example, `numDocs\n` or `numDocs\t`)

Comment: @coldspeed - will get that for you in a sec

Comment: Ah dang it - @RafaelC is right. Leading whitespace...I am so embarrassed.

Comment: @coldspeed - that's a handy command - I'll remember it